# expanded UITableviewCell height not manageable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using [this](https://github.com/fernandospr/FSParallaxTableView) in my app and i am create two identifiers for UITableview one is "normal cell" and another one is "expended cell" which will show when someone tap on a "normal cell". my problem is this that I can not manage heights of both cells separately for example I want normal cell height to be 120 and extended cell is to be 60. But if I change height in heightForRowAtIndexPath then both cells showing same height. here is my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FSParallaxTableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = nil;
    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandedIndexPath]) {
        cellIdentifier = @"ExpandedCell";
    }
    else {
        cellIdentifier = @"NormalCell";
    }
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[FSParallaxTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    if ([[cell reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"ExpandedCell"]) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
    if ([[cell reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"NormalCell"]) {
        [cell.cellImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmllink]]
                              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];
        cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // disable touch on expanded cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([[cell reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"ExpandedCell"]) {
        return;
    }
    // deselect row
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                             animated:NO];
    // get the actual index path
    indexPath = [self actualIndexPathForTappedIndexPath:indexPath];
    // save the expanded cell to delete it later
    NSIndexPath *theExpandedIndexPath = self.expandedIndexPath;
    // same row tapped twice - get rid of the expanded cell
    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandingIndexPath]) {
        self.expandingIndexPath = nil;
        self.expandedIndexPath = nil;
    }
    // add the expanded cell
    else {
        self.expandingIndexPath = indexPath;
        self.expandedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[indexPath row] + 1
                                                    inSection:[indexPath section]];
    }
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    if (theExpandedIndexPath) {
        [theTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[theExpandedIndexPath]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
    if (self.expandedIndexPath) {
        [theTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.expandedIndexPath]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
    [tableView endUpdates];
    // scroll to the expanded cell
    [self.theTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                     animated:YES];
}
```

can anyone please help me resolving this issue I want to set height for both cells separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below code in heightForAtIndexpath method

```
 if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandedIndexPath]) {
    return 60.0;
}
else 
   return 120.0f;
```

Comment: i applied this one but app crashes on launch. thanks

Comment: if u r having two different custom cell for two section,u can check indexpath.section number in if statement.

Comment: in my uitable i am having 1 section with 2 cells one is normal and second one is extended.

Comment: if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandedIndexPath]) {
     //height for expanded
    }
    else {
        //height for normal
    }

Comment: Thanks problem solved :) please post it i will mark it right. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    if ([[cell reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"ExpandedCell"]) {
        return 60;
    }
    if ([[cell reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"NormalCell"]) {
        return 120;
    }
}
```

Comment: reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier (null) - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the height of table view cell separately. you can set the height separately according as the row.In following code i have set the 1st row height 35, 2nd row height 70 and rest of the row will have height 65.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        switch (indexPath.row)

        {
            case 0:

                return 35;
                break;

            case 1:
                return 70;
                break;

            default:

                return 65;
                break;

        }


    }
```

Comment: this is not what i am asking for. please read my question once again.